# How to serve cloudfront assets via https with rails on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront to serve assets for my rails app on heroku. Over http this works fine. But when I access my website via https, assets don't load, and I get this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

Things I tried:

- Adding https:// to the front of the URL in rails config.
- Setting origin protocol policy to https only on cloudfront.
- Installing Rack Cors.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this option

**app/config/environments/production.rb**

```
# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
config.force_ssl = true

config.action_controller.asset_host = "<YOUR DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net"
```

**Documentation** at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn#testing comments a warning about this:

> If you are wanting to serve Cloudfront assets using SSL you can simply
>   use HTTPS on the distribution domain given to you by Amazon. Note,
>   whilst you can create CNAME’s for this purpose, serving Cloudfront
>   assets over your CNAME and SSL has an attached cost.